# Jasmine tests through bamboo?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, bamboo, jasmine-node

I would like to integrate the jasmine tests with bamboo, but I'm not sure is it possible.
The best what I found so far is https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bamboo-nodejs-plugin which support just mocha tests. I would like to know is there any way to change node-jasmine output to be compatible with bamboo.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Resolved:

Using option --junitreport and than use that report in bamboo to show the results,

Comment: Do you happen to know whether this works through Karma as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is 3 years too late, but hopefully it can help some other people aswell.

For Karma you can use karma-junit-reporter npm package.

install it and add this to your Karma config file

```
config.set({
    reporters: ['progress', 'junit'],
    ...
```

Then you can run your test and it will generate a JUnit xml file.

Use the JUNIT parser in bamboo and read this file. It should pick up your tests then.